# Comparar tablas, ver la diferencia y registros nuevos

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

Tengo un base de datos de un sistema de stock(BD1) y otra base(BD2) que la tengo para comparar, puedo hacer la comparación de las dos tablas que necesito, pero si la tabla de la base 1(bd1.t1) tiene un registro nuevo, la consulta muestra la diferencia de la bd1.t1 pero nos sus registro nuevos.

los campos de las tablas son

```
BD1 -> ID, STOCK, CANTIDAD, DEP  
BD2 -> CC_ID, CC_STOCK, CC_CANTIDAD, CC_DEP
```

la query que hago es:

```
SELECT 
  BD1.dbo.sta19.cod_articu, BD1.dbo.STA19.cant_stock 
  FROM
    BD1.dbo.sta19 inner join BD2.dbo.ComparadorStock
    ON 
    (BD1.dbo.sta19.cant_stock != BD2.dbo.ComparadorStock.CC_CANT_STOCK
      AND
      BD1.DBO.STA19.COD_ARTICU = BD2.dbo.ComparadorStock.CC_COD_ARTICU ) 
WHERE
BD1.dbo.sta19.COD_DEPOSI = 1 order by BD1.dbo.sta19.cod_articu
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas haciendo un `INNER JOIN` el cual solo te recupera las filas de `BD1.dbo.sta19` que existan en `BD2.dbo.ComparadorStock`. Las nuevas, las que están en la primer tabla pero no en la segunda no aparecerán. Para esto necesitas un  `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT  BD1.dbo.sta19.cod_articu, 
        BD1.dbo.STA19.cant_stock 
    FROM BD1.dbo.sta19 A
    LEFT JOIN BD2.dbo.ComparadorStock B
        ON A.COD_ARTICU = B.CC_COD_ARTICU
    WHERE   A.COD_DEPOSI = 1 
            AND (A.cant_stock != B.CC_CANT_STOCK or B.CC_CANT_STOCK IS NULL)

    order by A.cod_articu
```

Comentarios:

- Te sugiero el uso de alias de tabla, que hace más compacto el código
- El `LEFT` te debería recuperar todas las filas de `BD1.dbo.sta19` dónde el stock sea distinto o no haya filas en `BD2.dbo.ComparadorStock` es decir, `(A.cant_stock != B.CC_CANT_STOCK or B.CC_CANT_STOCK IS NULL)`

Comment: muchas gracias, funciono exactamente como lo describiste.